# How to remove Indicator from Material3 NavigationBar item?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm using Material3 NavigationBar and don't want any indicator when the current item is selected. How can I disable it? I've tried multiple ways such as changing the indicatorColor to transparent, changing the indicatorColor to another color with alpha(0f) but nothing seems to work.

```
NavigationBarItem(
  selected = selected,
  onClick = { onItemClick(item) },
  colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(indicatorColor = Color.Transparent),
  icon = {
     NavigationItem(selected, item)
   }
)
```

What is:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: I think its not considering Color.Transparent . Maybe you can try setting indicator color to same as of background color of bottom bar(same color for parent and indicator)

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(indicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseOnSurface)
```

This fixed the problem for me.. basically you need to set the same color as its background so its not recognizable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).