How to change the purple stuff?
I created a navigationbottom in my layout but there is an animation when selecting one of the icons which I don't need. I want to change or delete the light purple animation, how do I do it? I use the iguana version of Android Studio and the Kotlin language (I use material3)
enter image description here

in compose? or xml? also "the purple stuff" also, this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/76803185/15749574

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
